# Regex for two digit number

Tags: javascript, regex

If i do:

```
var pageNum= 2;

nextLink = http://mydomain.com/?paged=1 

nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/?paged=[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

I get

```
nextLink = 'http://mydomain.com/?paged=2';
```

But if I go:

```
var pageNum= 12;

nextLink = http://mydomain.com/?paged=10 

nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/?paged=[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

I get

```
netLink = 'http://mydomain.com/?paged=120';
```

When I want:

```
nextLink = 'http://mydomain.com/?paged=12';
```

So, how can I use a two digit number (11, 12, 13, 14 etc) and replace it with the pageNum variable (which can be both a one and two digit number).

Thank's!

Comment: Use `[0-9]*` instead of `[0-9]?`. See how [quantifiers work](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: The start of your regex should go `/\/\?...` (You forgot to escape the `?`) You'll also need to change your replacement string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code would be,

```
nextLink = nextLink.replace(/paged=[0-9]+/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

You failed to put `+`, symbol which means one or more times so that it would match one or more numbers following the string `paged=`. And also remove the `?` quantifier which does a shortest match.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fS4qE8)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any good resources for learning regex better. I often struggle with ttem.

Comment: @user3345564 good, this www.regular-expressions.info would help you to learn regex. If you have doubts in regex then don't forget to ask me.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways to write a regex checking for 2 digits, each with their own goal:

```
[0-9]+
```

means 1 or more digits;

```
\d\d
```

means exactly 2 digits and also works for digits which are in another base (like Hex);

```
[1-9][0-9]
```

means any number between 10 and 99.

```
[1-9][0-9]?
```

means any number between 1 and 99.

The best option depends on if you need support for triple digit numbers as well, and if you need to support a page 0. if you need triple numbers, you can go with Avinash' solution. if you only want those with double digits, go with [1-9][0-9]. if you want both single and double digits, go with my 4th solution.